# .Net Core Razor Pages with Multiple Routes

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I configure my razor page to accept multiple routes? For example, if I have a razor page **./Pages/Inovices/Overview.cshtml**. I need this page to handle requests for **~/invoices** AND **~/invoices/overview**. Currently I'm using Handler methods on an Index.cshtml but it feels like there should be an easier way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a convention for your page, using [`AddPageRoute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-a-page-route). Here's what it would look like for your example:

```cs
services.AddMvc(...)
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Invoices/Overview", "invoices");
    });
```

This adds a new route for the page but also keeps the existing route as is.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario where I needed to support multiple routes for razor pages and also needed to preserve URLs from razor pages that had been renamed so that bookmarks continued to work. To solve this I opted to use redirects instead. Here is how:

- In my Startup.cs file, I added a `HandleRedirects` method that defines the redirect middleware as well as the routes to redirect:

```cs
private void HandleRedirects(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Old Url, New Url
    var redirects = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        {"/Reports/BatchReport", "/Reports/BatchDetailReport" }
    };

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (redirects.TryGetValue(context.Request.Path, out var redirectUrl))
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
            return;
        }

        await next();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    HandleRedirects(app);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // ...
}
```